# How to Authenticate to MS SQL with a MS Access Form

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access 2013 Front end application that links tables to a MS Sequel Server Back end. When the user starts the application a dialogue box is asking for the SQL authentication.
I would like to provide a nice looking form to have the user login and pass that to MS Sequel.

How do I get the data from the form and pass it to MS Sequel or to the DNS that I am using.
Thanks
Todd

Answer (score 1):

You can have a default form pop up, and after they've input their credentials you would pass the login info to SQL like so:

```
Dim cnComments As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String

'Set up the connection string
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=YourServerName;
           INITIAL CATALOG=YourDatabaseName;
           UID=FormUserName;PWD=FormPassword;"
cnComments.Open strConn
```